# Top n tests failing most frequently in TeamCity

Tags: test-management

We're considering including top n test failing most frequently into smoke test suite. We want to test things that have tendency to break.

How can we find such tests in [TeamCity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) 6?

I see no related statistics in UI. Is there a way to access this through DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't use team city, but this question at stackoverflow seems to be a starting point: [tests failed within 120 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975527/in-teamcity-is-there-a-way-of-seeing-a-report-of-tests-ordered-by-failed-most-o).